# Reading short from file

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to read a short from a binary file, but I end up with a lot of 0's

This is the write function

```
void AudioBuffer::WriteToFile(const string& strFilename)
{
  fstream fout(strFilename.c_str(), ios::out|ios::binary);
  short sample;
  for (VECTOR_SHORT_ITER iter = m_vectorSamples.begin(); iter !=  m_vectorSamples.end(); iter++)
  {
    sample = (short) *iter;
    fout.write((char *) &sample, sizeof(short));
  }
  fout.close();
}
```

And this is what I've got for the reading function, I'm aware of the possible overflow with atoi

```
  void AudioBuffer::FileToBuffer(const string& strFilename)
  {
      fstream fin(strFilename.c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary);
      short iSample;
      char *temp = new char[sizeof(short)];

      cout<<"Samples Output"<<endl;
      while(!fin.eof())
      {
          fin.read(temp,sizeof(short));
          iSample = atoi(temp);
          cout<<iSample< " ";
          m_vectorSamples.push_back(iSample);
          *temp = NULL;
       }
      fin.close();
  }
```

Also, clearing the char pointer by doing the *temp = NULL isn't the best thing right?

Thanks

Comment: Printing out temp makes no sense.  Even though temp is a character array, it is storing the bit representation of your shorts.  Print out iSample instead.

Comment: Also, you do not have to clear out temp, but if you absolutely want to do so, you should use memset: `memset(temp, 0, sizeof(short));`

Comment: @MustafaOzturk Yeah sorry you're right, but I'm still not getting the correct data, just mostly 0's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're just writing raw bits into the file, you want to read the same way, something on this order:

```
void AudioBuffer::FileToBuffer(const string& strFilename)
{
    ifstream fin(strFilename.c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary);
    short iSample;

    cout<<"Samples Output"<<endl;
    while(fin.read((char *)&iSample,sizeof(short)))
    {
        cout<<iSample<< " ";
        m_vectorSamples.push_back(iSample);
    }
}
```